# SSH key authentication fails with error "Failed publickey for [USERNAME] from [CLIENT IP] port [PORT] ssh2"

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, openssh

NOTE: I've replaced all occurrences of the server's IP address with [SERVER IP] and all occurrences of the client's IP with [CLIENT IP].

I'm trying to get a key-based ssh connection between my Ubuntu 20.04 machine (local) and a RedHat machine (server). Among other things, I have:

- Uploaded my public key to the server (in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys)
- Set the permissions of authorized_keys and my private key
- Modified my config file (shown below)
- Restarted sshd numerous times

I can successfully connect via password authentication, but I'd like to get key-based authentication working.

The part of my config file relevant to this server is:

```
Host [HOSTNAME]
    Hostname [SERVER IP]
    User [USER]
    PubKeyAuthentication yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_[HOSTNAME]_2
```

The log files are long, so I've picked out the most relevant looking section:

```
debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 501/503 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for [USER] from [CLIENT IP] port [PORT] ssh2
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x7ff2143198f0 is not allowed
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 22
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg ssh-rsa
debug3: Wrote 40 bytes for a total of 2309
Connection closed by [CLIENT IP]
```

But I am not an expert at networking by any means, so this may be too late in the file to see anything. The full logs can be provided upon request.

Below is my sshd_config file:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd(8) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords yes

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

UsePAM yes
```

Comment: Enable verbose logging/debug on both client and server. Inspects logs on both sides. Closed by client IP likely means the client is closing the connection but the advanced/verbose logs on both client and server side may help narrow down further.

Comment: I've enabled DEBUG3 (-vvv or -ddd) logging on both client and server - the client is closing the connection because it has no other authentication methods available. The server rejects the public key, and I've disabled password authentication, because I can access the server physically, and I was trying to force key-based authentication.

I'm not very good at networking, so inspecting the logs is only helping me so much, but it seems to me that the issue is something to do with the keys themselves, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: It's best if you just provide us with the entire OpenSSH configuration file.  When you do that provide an output of `ls -alh` to provide the permissions on the keys themselfs.

Comment: @Ramhound Are you asking for the config file in the .ssh directory, or sshd_config?

Comment: What reason does the server say for rejecting the public key?

Comment: Your OpenSSH Server configuration file

Comment: Check the line ending type of the `authorized_keys` file where you put the public keys for those you authorize. Check if it's `CRLF`, `LF`, etc. and change accordingly if needed. Afterwards, restart the server of the `sshd` service and see if that does it for you.

Comment: "debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys" It looks like somehow you told `ssh` to use authorized_keys as a private key file. Please [edit] your question to show your entire ssh config file (or at least any sections that mention authorized_keys), and show exactly how you're running the ssh command.

Comment: @Ramhound I've edited my question to include sshd_config (which should be the openSSH config file). The command I run to get into the server is "ssh -vvv teststand", which uses the settings in ~/.ssh/config, the relevant section of which is in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating many weeks later for anyone who stumbles across this in a search for a similar issue.

I forgot that RSA keys were deprecated by openSSH a little while ago. The key I was using was RSA. Changing the key type to ecdsa fixed the issue.

Comment: Had the samue issue. RSA didn't work, then tried ECSDA with 521 bits after finding this post. Didn't work, but then ECSDA with the default 256 bits finally worked. Thanks for posting your solution, it helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

Change loglevel to DEBUG3 (maximum) and in my situation I found :

```
sshd[3478]: debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/root/.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory
```

I was simply using the wrong username (root in place of the masteruser) with my "ssh root@localhost".